# Make volley http request during app installation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite, android-volley

I want to make a volley http request only once and it should be during the time the app is installed.

I achieved this by making the http request in onCreate() method of SQLiteOpenHelper class which fetch data from remote MySQL ready for use. The problem I however runs into is that, after the app installation finishes, the app is presented with blank screen(fragment hosted on the main Activity). But when I close the app and opens for the second time, it is able to fetch data from the SQLite onto the screen.

Is there something special I have to do in the onCreate() method to **ensure that the app runs only after the volley request finishes?**

Here is my code.
**SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate()**

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(final SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_NOTICE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ROSTER_TABLE);

        /*Perform One time sync operations from remote MySQL*/
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ContextGetter.getAppContext());

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                if(response == null || response.length() == 0){
                    return;
                }

                if(response.has("notices")){
                    //Save to notices table
                    try {
                        JSONArray notices = response.getJSONArray("notices");
                        for (int i = 0; i < notices.length(); i++) {
                           JSONObject noticeObject = notices.getJSONObject(i);
                            String noticeID = noticeObject.getString(NOTICE_ID_KEY);
                            String noticeTitle = noticeObject.getString(NOTICE_TITLE_KEY);
                            String noticeBody = noticeObject.getString(NOTICE_BODY_KEY);
                            String dateCreated = noticeObject.getString(NOTICE_DATE_KEY);

                            NoticeItem noticeItem = new NoticeItem();
                            noticeItem.setId(Integer.parseInt(noticeID));
                            noticeItem.setTitle(noticeTitle);
                            noticeItem.setBody(noticeBody);
                            try {
                                noticeItem.setDate(formatDate(dateCreated));
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            //Save to SQLite
                            createNoticeBoard(noticeItem, db);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                //If roster available
                if(response.has("rosters")){
                    //Save to roster table
                    try {
                        JSONArray rosters = response.getJSONArray("rosters");
                        for (int i = 0; i <rosters.length() ; i++) {
                            JSONObject rosterObject = rosters.getJSONObject(i);
                            String rosterID = rosterObject.getString(ROSTER_ID_KEY);
                            String rosterOwner = rosterObject.getString(ROSTER_OWNER_KEY);
                            String rosterDate = rosterObject.getString(ROSTER_DATE_KEY);
                            String rosterShift = rosterObject.getString(ROSTER_SHIFT_KEY);

                            //Check to verify that the user actually owns that roster later by using shared preference
                            RosterItem rosterItem = new RosterItem();
                            rosterItem.setSyncNumber(Integer.parseInt(rosterID));
                            rosterItem.setStaffNumber(rosterOwner);
                            rosterItem.setShift(rosterShift);
                            try {
                                rosterItem.setDate(formatDate(rosterDate));
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            createRoster(rosterItem, db);
                        }
                    }catch(JSONException e){
                        Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: "+ e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Log.d(TAG, "VolleyError "+error.getMessage());
            }
        });


        //Add to requestQueue
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

**Fragment class**

```
public class NoticeListFragment extends Fragment{

    private static final String TAG = "NoticeListFragment";

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private NoticeListAdapter mNoticeListAdapter;


    public NoticeListFragment() {
        //Requires empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "Notices onCreate() called");

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateUI(); //In case data changes
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called");
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        //Inflate layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notice_list, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager linearManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearManager);

        updateUI();
        return rootView;
    }


    /*View Holder*/
    private class NoticeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        private NoticeItem mNoticeItem;

        public CardView mCardView;
        public TextView mTextViewTitle;
        public TextView mTextViewDate;
        public TextView mTextViewBody;

        public NoticeViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            mTextViewBody = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_notice_summary);
            mTextViewTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_notice_title);
            mTextViewDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_notice_date);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        //Bind properties to views

        private void bindNotice(NoticeItem noticeItem){
            mNoticeItem = noticeItem;
            mTextViewTitle.setText(noticeItem.getTitle());
            mTextViewDate.setText(noticeItem.getDate());
            mTextViewBody.setText(noticeItem.getSummary());

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = NoticePagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), mNoticeItem.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    /*Adapter*/
    private class NoticeListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoticeViewHolder>{

        //private Context mContext;
        private List<NoticeItem> listItems;


        //Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset you have)
        public NoticeListAdapter(List<NoticeItem> data) {
            //this.mContext = context;
            this.listItems = data;
        }


        @Override
        public NoticeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            //Create a new view
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.notice_lists_card, parent, false);
            //Set the view size, margin, padding and layout parameters
            NoticeViewHolder vh = new NoticeViewHolder(view);

            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(NoticeViewHolder holder, int position){

            final NoticeItem noticeItem = listItems.get(position);
            //Bind data properties to views here...
            holder.bindNotice(noticeItem);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return listItems.size();
        }

        public void setNotices(List<NoticeItem> notices){
                listItems = notices;
        }
    }

    //Bind adapter to recycler view
    private void updateUI(){
        NoticeLab noticeLab = NoticeLab.get(getActivity());
        List<NoticeItem> notices = noticeLab.getNotices();

        if(mNoticeListAdapter == null){
            mNoticeListAdapter = new NoticeListAdapter(notices);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mNoticeListAdapter);
        }else{

            mNoticeListAdapter.setNotices(notices);
            mNoticeListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just implement a splashscreen?

Comment: Ok. I already have a splash screen in place. You mean I should do the http calls during the period of the splash screen?

Comment: Yup. A slpashscreen means your app is currently in an unusable state, that it has to do some initializations (fetching some data from the server for ex) in order to be usable. Seems like that's what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin But my point is that I want to do this only once. (during the app first time installation) A splash screen will always be there anytime the user starts the app. How do I use the splash screen to ensure the initialization only happens once?

Comment: That means a splash screen cannot solve the problem. Because I want the initialization to run only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to make a volley http request only once and it should be during the time the app is installed.

You do not get control when your app is installed.

> Is there something special I have to do in the onCreate() method to ensure that the app runs only after the volley request finishes?

Volley is asynchronous. That is the complete and entire point behind using Volley. Immediately after you call `requestQueue.add(request);`, *your `onCreate()` method continues executing*, while Volley performs the network I/O on a background thread.

Some options are:

1. Get rid of all the Volley code, by packaging your starter data in the APK as an asset and [using `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to deploy the packaged database on first run of your app.
2. Do not use Volley. Instead, use something with a synchronous network I/O option (`HttpURLConnection`, OkHttp, etc.), and perform synchronous network I/O here. You should always be using your `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass on a background thread, in case the database needs to be created or updated. So your `onCreate()` method of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` should always be called on a background thread, and you would not need yet another background thread for the network I/O. Then, you can be sure that by the time `onCreate()` ends that your starter data is there... except if you do not have Internet connectivity, or your server is down, etc.
3. Move all your initialization logic to something else, such as an `IntentService`. Have it create the database (using the `IntentService`'s own background thread) and have it do the network I/O (again, using a synchronous API, since `IntentService` has its own background thread). Only start your UI once the `IntentService` is done with its work. You are in better position here to deal with connectivity errors via some sort of retry policy, while presenting some temporary UI to the user while that work is going on (e.g., `ProgressBar`).

Comment: Your second option looks good for me. But how can I implement this in my case. Any pointers?

Comment: @ultrasamad: I strongly encourage the third option `HttpURLConnection` has been around for ~15 years and is well-covered in books, Web sites, etc. Using OkHttp to perform a synchronous GET request [is even easier](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#synchronous-get).

Comment: I did some few readings around the IntentService, My question however is that will IntentService make sure the operation (initialization network calls) run only once and not during subsequent starts of the app. I'm naive in this.

Comment: @ultrasamad: If the database file does not exist, you know that you need to download the starter data. See [`getDatabasePath()` on `Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)).

Comment: For the meantime, I implemented the synchronous get request of  Okhttp under Async Task, but it is still the same problem of UI not waiting for request to complete

Comment: Volley can be used in both sync and async requests.